# Hereditary compactness and discrete subspaces of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$

Tags: general-topology

If a compact space $K$ is hereditarily separable then it doesn't contain discrete subspaces of size continuum. But, the reverse implication is true? If not, are there easy counterexamples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we even know that no *uncountable* discrete subspace exists, which is a stronger conclusion, in general. And the reverse implication in that case is consistently true:

Theorem: if [Martin's axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin's_axiom) holds and the [Continuum Hypothesis (CH)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) fails, then a compact Hausdorff space that does not contain an uncountable discrete subspace, is hereditarily separable.

If the Continuum Hypothesis holds, there exists examples of compact Hausdorff spaces that are hereditarily Lindelöf (so in particular no uncountable discrete subspace exists) but are not separable. These are so-called compact L-spaces. They also exist when a [Suslin line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem) exists, e.g., and under other assumptions as well.

So no easy examples, as in some models of set theory we have counterexamples against the reverse implication. And in other models we have a reverse implication for a stronger condition (assuming no uncountable discrete subspace exists).

But if CH fails, we also have a counterexample (albeit a boring one): $\omega_1 + 1$ is compact and Hausdorff (even hereditarily normal), has no subspaces at all of size continuum (if CH fails!) and is not separable. And as said, under CH we have even stronger counterexamples. So in no model of ZFC the reverse implication holds.

So probably some absolute (without any axioms) example can exist (so a non-separable compact Hausdorff space that has no discrete subspace of size continuum), though I cannot think of one now...

Comment: Thank you @HennoBrandsma ! Could you give me the reference of the first theorem?

Comment: It's certainly in the classical book "consequences of Martin's Axiom" by Fremlin. I'll try to find the original paper

Comment: It follows from Szentmiklóssy's theorem "S-spaces and L-spaces under Martin's Axiom", Coll. Math. Soc. János Bolyai, 23, Budapest, 1978, II, 1139-1145". The main result there is that under MA($\omega_1$) no compact S-spaces exist, and the result follows from that, I think, with some extra arguments, as found in Fremlin.

Comment: Fremlin proves (44H, page 220 in his book) that for a compact Hausdorff space $X$, if MA and not CH holds, it is equivalent to be hereditarily ccc (which is equivalent to no uncountable discrete subspaces), hereditarily Lindelöf or hereditarily separable. It's a summary result of a lot of different things in the book (also partly due to Juhasz).

Comment: Thank you @HennoBrandsma! :)

Comment: @Heracles Glad to be able to help! Still would be nice to have an absolute counterexample to the weaker implication, though.